# What is the proper way to handle imported files in iOS 9?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, ios9

My app includes the ability to open **.plist** files in it. My info.plist file has all the necessary entitlements, and opening the document in my app works fine. The problem is I don't know the proper way to handle imported files, especially after the `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` method is deprecated in iOS 9. Also, it is possible my app will be open to a list of local files when the file is imported, so I need to be able refresh that list when the file is received.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it (although it may not be the proper way).

1. Declare a global variable `fileURL` that will be an `NSURL?` using `var fileURL: NSURL?` outside of any class declarations.
2. Implement the following method in **AppDelegate.swift**:

   ```
   func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool

       fileURL = url       
       // The next two lines make sure the app open up to the first screen (the one marked as "Is Initial View Controller" in the Main.storyboard file.
       // If you would like to handle the file in a different ViewController then you will need to modify the code below.
       let rootViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController()
       self.window?.rootViewController = rootViewController

       return true

   }
   ```
3. In the class declaration for the **UIViewController** (or subclass such as **UITableViewController**) implement the following method:

   ```
   override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

       if fileURL != nil {

           // handle file actions here (don't forget to use fileURL! not fileURL)

       }

   }
   ```